# Using google library in coldfusion without using Java library

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Referring to the [following](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) library and my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222450/creating-an-equivalent-library-in-coldfusion) thread, I have two questions:

Question #1: I have decided not to mess up with Java Libraries and hence could anyone tell me if there is another way to figure out how to use the `libphonenumber` library in coldfusion?

Question #2: As discussed in my previous thread, that many people are porting it to different programming languages like JavaScript, Ruby, PHP as they are not written in Java. The google library `libphonenumber` is written in PHP and I am wondering why someone would port it to PHP language.

Comment: What problem are you having using the Java library? It should be pretty straightforward. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @MattBusche The server with which I am working has lot of other imp stuff going on and hence I am trying to avoid Java library approach. I don't want to restart that server after making changes and break any other thing.

Comment: Why not try the JavaLoader.cfc (see link in my answer)? It is a dynamic class loader allows you to use jars without requiring you add them to the core CF class path or restart.

Answer (score 1):

(This is more of a comment, but is a little too long)

Seems like this was already answered in the comments of your other thread, but to reiterate:

> Is there another way to use a java library from CF?

No. There is basically only one way to use java libraries from CF. Add the jar(s) to the class path and use `createObject`.  You could also use a dynamic class loader like [Mark Mandel's JavaLoader.cfc](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/) (or the rip of that project [baked into CF10+](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7fff.html)).  However, ultimately they all do the same thing.

Since using java libraries is pretty simple in CF, I am curious why you do not want to use it. While I suppose you could rewrite it in pure CFML, I would ask why? The whole point of libraries is reuse, which saves development time. Since there already is a compatible library available to you, there is not much point in rewriting it. Not unless you are doing it as a learning exercise.

> The google library libphonenumber is written in PHP

No. There is *port* that is [written in PHP](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php). The "official" project is "a Java, C++ and Javascript library.". So it sounds like your options are the java version (server side) or javascript version (client side use). That is it.

> I am wondering why someone would port it to PHP language.

Because the java library is not compatible with every platform out there, PHP being one of them. If a developer on an unsupported platform wanted to use it, they have two choices: port it or write their own from scratch. Since the google project already did most of the heavy lifting, porting is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So only other option seems like rewriting whole thing in CFML or use the existing Java library.

Comment: Yes. Though you omitted the client side java*script* version. I really do not see the value in rewriting something that already exists. Why is it you do not want to use the java library?

Comment: As Leigh pointed out, use the JavaLoader CFC.  This way you can load anything from the `libphonenumber` JAR without needing to restart a service or impact the library structure of the service.